# Trying to create pivot table vba with dynamic range

Tags: vba, dynamic, pivot-table, type-mismatch

I want to create a pivot table with a dynamic range that refers to another tab. I keep getting "**Run-time error '13' - Type mismatch**" after the comment "*define pivot cache*".  Any suggestions?

```
Sub InsertExportPivotTables()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

'*************Actions by study
'Insert a New Blank Worksheet for Actions by Study
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Actions by Study").Delete 'deletes worksheet if already exists
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Actions by Study"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Actions by Study")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("export")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Range("A" & DSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set PRange = DSheet.Range(DSheet.Cells(6, 1), DSheet.Cells(LastRow, "U"))

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
        TableName:="ActionsbyStudy01", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

End Sub
```

Comment: oops it wont let me edit it now, but the SourceData should be set to PRange. I used the actually address in this instance and it seemed to work.

Comment: You have to tell us what the error is, please update the question.

Comment: sorry, error is run-time error'13': type mismatch

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Comment: The error is occuring at the set PCache statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass ***PivotCaches.Create*** a named range but not a **Range** object.

> The *SourceData* argument is required if *SourceType* isn't **xlExternal** .
>   It should be passed a Range (when *SourceType* is either **xlConsolidation**
>   or **xlDatabase** ) or an Excel Workbook Connection object (when
>   *SourceType* is **xlExternal** ). When passing a Range, it is recommended to
>   either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell
>   range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string.
>
> **Passing a *Range* object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly**.

<sub>(More info at [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcaches-create-method-excel))</sub>

Comment: how would i go about passing the named range as a string?

Comment: I think: `ActiveWorkbook.Names("yourRangeName").RefersToRange`